# Querying date field in MongoDB with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to query documents in `MongoDB` using `findOne()`, but it's not working. The field I'm trying to filter by is 'date', and I'm not sure if perhaps it's a special word I shouldn't be using when inserting docs. Is there something I'm missing?

Mongo Docs:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52c271a5d1344a7a326c0d48"),
    "author" : "User",
    "title" : "Fourth post",
    "body" : "This is the fourth post",
    "date" : "1000000"
}
```

Node:

```
var postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    author:String,
    title:String,
    body:String,
    date:Number,
    attachments:Array
}),
    post = mongoose.model('post', postSchema);

exports.getPost = function(id, callback) {
    console.log(id);
    post.findOne({date:id}, function(err, item) {
        console.log(item);
    });
}
```

Console: (querying `http://localhost:8080/posts/1000000`)

```
1000000
null
```

Comment: Do `console.log(typeof id)` and you'll see the problem.

Comment: how do you pass your id? Or how do you call function?

Comment: do you have an error in err?

Comment: Try using parseInt(id)

Comment: @BradM: That was it. I threw in `{date:parseInt(id)}` and it worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`{ "date" : "1000000" }` in your Mongo doc seems suspect. Since it's a number, it should be `{ date : 1000000 }`

It's probably a type mismatch. Try `post.findOne({date: "1000000"}, callback)` and if that works, you have a typing issue.